# How to fix Sentry User Feedback Error - Cannot read property 'showReportDialog' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, sentry

I've been trying to get a User Feedback dialog to show when I click on a certain button, but I've had some trouble. I successfully got it to work when I make a call my API and end up getting an error shown first.

However I created a button that would trigger a call to Sentry.showReportDialog, but I get a 'Cannot read property 'showReportDialog' of undefined' error. I've tried using Sentry.capture Message/Exception/Error to generate an eventId, but I still got the same error. This is my current code that's failing, but I've modified it a decent amount and was still getting the same undefined error for showReportDialog, even when I tried the method that worked with my API call. This web application is running using Ember.js v3.5.1 and in my package.json the dependency for sentry is
"@sentry/browser": "^4.5.3"

```
// works
try {
    $('.ember-application').addClass('request-loading');
    this.model.setProperties(properties);
    return yield this.model.save();
} catch (err) {
    // Get feedback from user through sentry
    Sentry.init({
        dsn:'https://ec08003a76fa4b6e8f111237ed3ed8e1@sentry.io/1369772',
        beforeSend(event) {
            if (event.exception) {
            Sentry.showReportDialog({ eventId: event.event_id });
        }
        return event;
    },
});
```

}

```
// does not work
try {
    throw new Error();
} catch (e) {
    var eventId = yield Sentry.captureException(e, function(sendErr, eventId) {
        // This callback fires once the report has been sent to Sentry
        if (sendErr) {
            console.error('Failed to send captured exception to Sentry');
        } else {
            console.log('Captured exception and send to Sentry successfully');
            console.log(eventId);
        }
    });
    console.log(eventId);
    Sentry.showReportDialog({ eventId: eventId });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Answer for 2022

If anyone stumbles on this question looking for the answer, please don't use the other answer with `yield` and everything else. You don't need to generate and catch a fake error just to submit a report to Sentry, but you do need an `eventId`. You can get that from the return value of `Sentry.captureMessage(...)` like this:

```js
const eventId = Sentry.captureMessage(`User has some feedback`);
Sentry.showReportDialog({
  eventId,
  title: 'Want to share some feedback?',
  subtitle: 'Great!',
  subtitle2: `If not, just click 'close' below.`,
  labelComments: 'What would you like us to know?',
  labelSubmit: 'Submit Feedback'
});
```

Obviously, this has to be after you've already called `Sentry.init(...)` however you do it. You can set the labels however you want and read more about it in the [documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/enriching-events/user-feedback/).

If you do it like this, the message "User has some feedback" (or whatever message you use) will appear in your Issues list in Sentry with a blue mark next to it instead of the orangish-red exceptions. That's helps to distinguish it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code ended up working for me

```
try {
        throw new Error();
    } catch (e) {
        Sentry.init({
            dsn: 'https://ec080033425613e7ed3ed8e1@sentry.io/1369772',
            beforeSend(event) {
                return event;
            },
        });
        var eventId = yield Sentry.captureException(e, function() {});
        Sentry.showReportDialog({
            eventId: eventId,
    });
}
```